# VBA use gradient colors when a condition fails

Tags: vba

How can I set a cell color to show a gradient of colors when a condition fails. I am new to Excel VBA programming and I came across a similar question on here that asked the questioner to use macro recorder to get the code. I have never used a macro recorder and would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction. Anyhow, I would like the following color gradient for a cell should a condition pass/fail.

This is the color gradient I am looking for:

[image]

** **UPDATE** **

I tried this with Conditional Formatting and my formula looks like this. Seems partly working but I am ending up coloring the cells that I should not be. See below:

[image]

Comment: What's the condition? Are you looking for VBA, or just to use conditional formatting?

Comment: I am looking to set it thru VBA code. The condition  is if the value of a specific value is 0, I want this color gradient. Thanks, Ben.

Comment: If IsNull(JSONObj("issues")(iCounter)("fields")("timeoriginalestimate")) Then --- is the condition.

Comment: You know what, come to think of it, I don't care if I am able to set it thru conditional formatting also :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest formatting though VBA instead of conditional formatting if this is a static color (not changed dynamically as the user is updating Excel).

Here's some generic code on formatting a cell with a gradient from the macro recorder (Selection is the cell we want to fill)

```vb
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlPatternLinearGradient
        .Gradient.Degree = 90
        .Gradient.ColorStops.Clear
    End With
    With Selection.Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(0)
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(1)
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
```

Comment: Sure, let me give this a spin.

Comment: @Jrules80: Of course you can use `.Color` instead of `.ThemeColor`. That will give you flexibility and consistency across devices.

Comment: Just for giggles, how does one go about doing this using the conditional formatting?

Comment: Go to conditional formatting -> New rule -> /Select whatever rule type/ -> Format... -> Fill -> Fill Effects

Comment: So, with conditional formatting, I am getting partial results. See my update in the question above. I am ending up coloring unwanted cells too. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: @Jrules80 Blank cells have technically a value of 0. You must check if the cell is blank. For instance:

`=AND(NOT(ISBLANK($F1)),$F1=0)`

Comment: Awesome. That did it.